# Can not find native library java.nativelibJCudaDriver-linux-x86_64.so

Tags: hadoop, java.library.path, jcuda, hadoop-native-library

I am trying to implement JCUDA code on Hadoop. However while running the application, it gives unsatisfied link error:

> can not load the native library "JCudaDriver-linux-x86_64" with base name "JCudaDriver"'

I have tried added the path to the library in `LIBJARS`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc. I have tried setting the variable in the Java code using `System.setProperty()`. I have also tried the variable `-Djava.library.path`. However nothing seems to be working.

Operating System: Linux
Jcuda version: 0.7.0
CUDA version: 7.0
Hadoop version: 1.2.1

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Kevin!

Comment: Hadoop spawns "child JVMs" on the nodes, and you might have to adjust your configuration with an **additional** setting of the `java.library.path` for the child VMs, as described in http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Task+Execution+%26+Environment (at least, I know that people once got this working, according to http://forum.byte-welt.net/byte-welt-projekte-projects/swogl-jcuda-jocl/jcuda/3188-jcuda-hadoop-exception.html ...)

Comment: I'm curious, was the issue resolved by setting the additional `java.library.path` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it was. Thanks for the help!